# How can I match the svnlook output in Perl?

Tags: perl, svn, svnlook

I'm running SVN on a Windows server, and I'm using Perl scripts to implement some pre-commit hooks. I'm seeing the following error message from TortoiseSVN:

> Error !!ScriptError!! Can't parse
>   line: _U path/to/files/trunk

and this is the script:

```
foreach my $line (`$svnlook changed -t "$txn" "$repos"`)
{
  chomp($line);
  if ($line !~ /([AUD]).\s\s(.+)$/)
  {
    print STDERR "!!Script Error!! Can't parse line: $line\n";
    exit(1);
  }
  else
  {
     # perform some actions 
  }
}

exit(0);
```

I tried replacing the regex with things like `/_([AUD]).\s\s(.+)$/` with no sucess - I even tried `/.*([AUD]).\s\s(.+)$/`.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Can you add a sample of how the error messages from TortoiseSVN looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a look into the SVN documentation I'm just guessing:
In the output above only one space is shown between U and the actual path, but you have `\s\s` in all your regexes.

[edit]
Ok, now I had a look into the [svnlook reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnlook.c.changed.html).  First, your regex fails for current versions of svnlook, as the output is specified as follows:

- The first two columns contain the status
- the path starts at the fifth column
- Status may be one of A (added), U (content changed), D (deleted), _U (properties changes), and UU (content + properties changed)

So, you should be able to match with something like `^([_AUD]+)\s+(.+)$`.  One can get more specific, but that ain't necessary.

If this doesn't match, please pipe the command's output to a file, and post the relevant part here.

Comment: I replaced it with :

if ($line !~ /^\s+([AUD])\s+(.+)$/)

but no success - it appears to be irritated by that leading underscore, but I'm wondering if that's actually an underscore or if it's something else like a mangled encoded character.

Comment: The last time I looked at the svnlook source code, it really was an underscore. I'd recommend looking at the source code to determine what really may be output.  The help isn't fully up-to-date nor accurate in  regards to the legal output.

Comment: yeah, I found that same documentation and updated the regex to this:

`if ($line !~ /^\s*(A|D|U|UU|_U)\s*(.+)$/)`

which works much better. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`if ($line !~ /^_?([AUD])\s+(.+)$/` should work fine.

Comment: this works much better for the complete set of svnlook identifiers:

`if ($line !~ /^\s*(A|D|U|UU|_U)\s*(.+)$/)`

Comment: Ah, yeah.  I missed the `UU` bit when I checked the documentation.